# Where to file a bug?

Tags: hardware-compatibility

There are lots of Linux distributions and every one of them is made according to maintainers point of view using different DE, package managers, kernels etc.

When some part of your hardware is failing to work properly reporting a bug on that should be forwarded to distro maintainers or directly to kernel maintainers?

How a novice user of linux can know where to go when something is not working correctly and all other resources (google, forums) failed to solve a problem?

Comment: Where is the bug? Bugs could be caused by developers, package maintainers, hardware manufacturers, etc., so you will have to use your best descretion in determining who is reponsible and should receive the bug report.  Sometimes software bugs can be filed with the package maintainer who has the choice to forward the bug on to the developer.

Comment: It sounds like that question is based on actual experience. Do you have a link to where you discussed that problem in a forum/Q&A site so we can use that as an in-context example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The first stop is your distribution bug tracker**, from there on you will be guided to the next step.

It is said that (unless you are able to reproduce the same bug in any distribution or that if you compile from sources and you are able to reproduce it in several systems) you should report downstream (i.e. at your distribution).

In doubt always report to your specific distribution bug tracker, be sure to read their guides, so the bug can be fixed in brevity (ie. no missing information that has to be teased out the reporter).

There are various guide for each distribution:

- [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)
- [Debian](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting)
- [RHEL based](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-abrt.html) (this seems to be the standard way to report bugs on RHEL and friends)
- [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reporting_Bug_Guidelines)
- [Linux Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lkml/reporting-bugs.html) Unless asked by downstream you MAY never do this.

Comment: Isn't [this site](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/) for reporting kernel's bugs ?

Comment: @banuy of course not. I listed the sites where you can report bugs in my answer. Unix & Linux is a Questions and Answers site, where people ask questions and get answers. I recommend you [reading the tour page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Well my question in comment had a link :)

Comment: @banuy ah, I didn't saw it, yeah, that is.

Comment: For Fedora/Redhat https://bugzilla.redhat.com/ seems to be the place, the link you provided for 'RHEL based' appears to be how to install ABRT... http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_file_a_bug_report may be better.